# Can't install on a HP Mini 210-1100

Tags: 10.10, installation, wubi, live-usb

I just can't seem to install Ubuntu on my Netbook, when trying to boot the liveusb the netbook just sits there and if i try to boot Ubuntu via WUBI it installs without a problem but there's nothing added to the Windows booloader and if i add the entry manually grub4dos just gives an error and does nothing.

The mini comes with an Instant-on Linux based OS, HP's Quickweb but i find it to be extremely slow, i disabled it thinking it may fix the issue of the liveusb not booting or WUBI not being added to the Windows bootloader, but it didn't helped.

it's specs are an Atom N455 ,1GB DDR3 RAM and and intel GMA3150.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem, was that i used a 64 bit ISO image, and the Atom CPU only supports 32 bit.

Answer (score 2):

I had a solution for my HP Mini 110, which may work for you. My issue was that Ubuntu would start booting, but the dots would stop at some point, and there would not be any disk activity on the USB key. The system was hung.

I remembered that there were *some* power management issues under some other version of ubuntu, so I added the options:

- acpi=off
- noapic

The first one is the one which seems to make the difference. The second one is harmless but is not required, as far as I can see.

To add this option do the following:

- When booting from the USB, if you made your USB key with unetbootin, Press TAB to edit the options.
- insert **acpi=off** on the command line. This is the line where you also see word like **quiet** or **splash**
- Boot your machine.

Proceed with the installation. When you will reboot, you will have a similar manual change to do the first time. You will need to add the same option on the boot line. This time, you select the first line, but instead of pressing Enter, press letter e to edit it.

Once the installed Ubuntu is started, you need to edit the file:

- **sudo vi /etc/defaults/grub**

insert the acpi=off on the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. Then enter the command:

- **sudo update-grub**

Your computer startup should be updated. My only issue on my HP Mini 110 is that when I do a shutdown, it does not completely shutdown. The disk is still properly flushed, and there is no apparent data loss. But this is better than no linux at all.

Comment: well, the problem is that nothing shows up, i'm using an sdcard to boot and set it to boot from it, but it gets stuck at the HP logo , unetbootin doesn't show, and on the BIOS there's no option to change the power management features.

Comment: the ubuntu iso works, i actually tried with mint as well and still nothing, and the sd card works as i installed my os with it. also the sd card reader on the netbook works as it let me installed the wubi based version BUT the wubi bootloader entry is not added to the windows bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Which program did you use to create the usb stick? Unetbootin (available in synaptics) nearly never let me down, while the ubuntu start up disk creator gave me trouble.

Comment: yep i used UnetbootIN

Comment: did you disable it or did you format the hd?

Comment: yes i disabled it quickweb so it boots straight into windows. i haven't done anything to the hd yet.